# How can I close TCP client during recv?

Tags: python, multithreading, recv

I have the following code:

```
s.settimeout( 300 )
while notend:
   data = s.recv()       
   datacheck()
   ...
```

The code above is running on a thread so if the user set the `notend` variable to False the thread will end. But in this case it won't exit immediately, it takes 300 second to exit, because of the `recv` function. How can exit from this thread?

```
# Wait all the threads
for thread in threading.enumerate():
   if thread is not threading.currentThread():
       thread.join()
```

Comment: Are you sure that's actually the problem? `recv` needs a parameter: `socket.recv(bufsize)`, otherwise a `TypeError` is raised. Could you show us a little more code?

Comment: yes the buffer size is there, I just forget to include that in the sampling code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - close s from another thread.  The recv() call will then return with an error, so allowing the thread that called it to clean up and terminate.

There is no need for timeouts, select() etc.

Comment: I just tested and its working fine, but I had to use the `shutdown`, because the close had no effect

Comment: Thanks for that news.  Close/shutdown/whatever, as long as its working fine, that's OK by me!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, if you have a blocking socket, `recv()` will block for the entire duration of the timeout. You could specify a shorter timeout, but that may not be what you want to do (what if the ping really is many thousands of milliseconds?).

Instead of simply trying to `recv()` all day, you could use a `select.poll` object to poll the socket of interest at a more frequent rate (smaller timeout), and call `recv()` only when the polling reports that there is some data to read. In between polls, you could break out of the polling loop if you discover at any point that `notend` is now false.

If your platform doesn't support `poll()`, then see if it supports `select()`. Then, you can use the `select.select()` function to accomplish more-or-less the same task.

Here's a reference for the described functionality:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#poll-objects
http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select

Comment: My problem is tha it is supported only Unix system `The poll() system call, supported on most Unix systems`

Comment: @iUngi does your platform have `select()`? Most platforms (including Windows) should. The `select()` call accomplishes the same task, but with slightly different semantics. (answer updated)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [socket.settimeout](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket#socket.socket.settimeout) because `recv` is a blocking method

Comment: Looks like he is: `s.settimeout( 300 )`

Comment: I know it's a blocking function, The server has 300 seconds to start sending the measured data, if there is a timeout than I will restart the measurement